# Change CSS3 Background image on <p> hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make the background image (that I set using the CSS3 "background" and "background-size") change when I hover over a certain paragraph.
I've tried:

**in jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('#web').hover(function () {
        $(this).css('background', '#000 url(space-image.png) center center fixed no-repeat');
    })
});
```

**in Javascript**

```
onMouseOver="document.getElementByName("body").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

and others with no luck.

Comment: This seems to work just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/W4JLB/

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
$(function(){
    $('#web').hover( function(){
          $(this).css('background', '#000 url(space-image.png) center center fixed no-repeat');
     }); // <-- you missed this, meaning 'end of hover function'
});
```

Also,

```
onMouseOver="document.getElementByName('body').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Currently, the browser will think the `onmouseover` function stops at the `"` before `body`. The browser will set everything between `"` and the second `"` to `onmouseover`. So that's:

```
document.getElementByName(
```

which doesn't quite work obviously. You'd need to change the first and last `"` into a `'`. That way, the browser will take everything between the `'`s as the `onmouseover` value which works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing this entirely with CSS3 pseudo-classes? In other words:

```
#web:hover {
    background: #000 url(space-image.png) center center fixed no-repeat;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Do you want to change the background image of the entire page or just a single element? If it's the entire page, then you'll want to substitute $('body') for $(this), since $(this) is just referring to the #web element that you're selecting in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/aBCqQ/

```
$(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).css({backgroundImage: "url(http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1234/1324629526_1020726ce3_m.jpg)"});
    },function(){
        $(this).css({backgroundImage: ""});
    });
});
```

Some observations with your non-jQuery code:

What does `onMouseOver` refer to?  Are you assigning that string to a variable?  The `onmouseover` property of an element must be in all lower case.

You have to escape quotes in your string with `\`.  So `...("body")...` becomes `...(\"body\")...`.

There is no `getElementByName` method.  There's a `getElementsByName` (plural), but did you really give an element a name attribute of "body"?  You can get the body element simply by: `document.body`.

Why use a string, you should use a function:

```
myElement.onmouseover = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").hover(function() {
    $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function() {
    $("p").css("font-size", "25px");
});
```

above example contain how to change the `background-color` and `font-size` using hover.